# XAML Designer throws Access Denied exception with VS2015 RTM

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I just did a fresh install of both Windows 10 + Visual Studio 2015 today, both RTM. When I create a new UWP app and double-click `MainPage.xaml`, the designer immediately crashes. Here is the stack trace:

```
System.Exception
Package could not be registered.

error 0x80070005: While processing the request, the system failed to register the windows.capability extension due to the following error: Access is denied.

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, String baseDirectory)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<StartTask>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

I've found [other](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5b1ea53a-723c-45bc-b261-51b8c18927ae/uwpvisual-2015-rc-can-not-load-designer-with-error-package-failed-updates-dependency-or?forum=wpdevelop) posts on MSDN that look like they have a similar stack trace, but different errors (usually about a corrupted package). Do those apply / is there another workaround for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Any chance it contains a user made control or class that maybe for some reason hasnt ported to vs2015?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to enable the "developer mode" of your Windows 10 system in order to enable debugging and designers for app development. See also this site: [Enable your device for development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn706236.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly after this.